# Qt: Create a new class with another parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a problem in instantiating a new class with another parameter.

My problem is to add something in a QList Asteroids Object. In Qt, I have this error message:

> cannot convert 'SettingsAsteroid' to 'SettingsAsteroid*' in assignment
>        this->settingsAsteroid = SettingsAsteroid();

Below are the relevant files of the class doing it, and I think other classes are not relevant.

Data in GameView.h :

```
#ifndef GAMEVIEW_H
#define GAMEVIEW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QList>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

#include "Asteroid.h"
#include "SettingsAsteroid.h"


class GameView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // Data
    int nbAsteroids;
    int nbAsteroidsAlive;
    SettingsAsteroid* settingsAsteroid;
    QList<Asteroid> asteroids;


    // Menu
    QPushButton *startgame;

    // Scène
    QGraphicsScene* grfxScene;

public:
    GameView();
    ~GameView();

private slots:

    void start();

};

#endif // GAMEVIEW_H
```

Source code in GameView.c :

```
#include "GameView.h"
#include <iostream>


GameView::GameView()
{
    int nbAsteroids = 0;
    int nbAsteroidsAlive = 0;

    // data de jeu
    this->settingsAsteroid = SettingsAsteroid();

    //Scene de debut
    this->grfxScene = new QGraphicsScene();
    grfxScene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600);
    this->grfxScene->addPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/armageddon.jpg"));

    setScene(this->grfxScene);

}

GameView::~GameView(){ }

void GameView::start()
{
    this->grfxScene->clear();

    int nbAsteroids = 4;
    int nbAsteroidsAlive = 4;

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nbAsteroids;i++) {
       asteroids.append(new Asteroid(settingsAsteroid));
    }
}
```

Constructor of Asteroid.c :

```
Asteroid::Asteroid(SettingsAsteroid settingsAsteroid)
```

Comment: Check this one `this->grfxScene = new QGraphicsScene();` and notice the difference.

Comment: I have change this:
    this->settingsAsteroid = new SettingsAsteroid();

and this:

       this->asteroids.append(new Asteroid(settingsAsteroid));

But it s don't work

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error

> cannot convert '`SettingsAsteroid`' to '`SettingsAsteroid*`' in assignment `this->settingsAsteroid = SettingsAsteroid();`

On the code:

```
this->settingsAsteroid = SettingsAsteroid();
```

You are attempting to convert a `SettingsAsteroid` into a `SettingsAsteroid*`, that is: a pointer to a `SettingsAsteroid` object.

Because `GameView` has a member `settingsAsteroid` which is a `SettingsAsteroid*`, you need to give it a pointer to a `SettingsAsteroid`, not a `SettingsObject` itself. You can do one of the following:

```
this->settingsAsteroid = new SettingsAsteroid();
```

Calling `new` will allocate memory for the required object (your `SettingsAsteroid`) and return a pointer to that memory, of type `SettingsAsteroid*`. Alternatively, if you already have some `SettingsAsteroid` object you could assign **it** instead:

```
SettingsAsteroid sa;
...
this->settingsAsteroid = &sa;
```

Comment: I have try:
In constructor:
    SettingsAsteroid sa;
    this->settingsAsteroid = &sa;
In start()
int i;
    for(i=0;i<nbAsteroids;i++) {
       this->asteroids.append(Asteroid(*settingsAsteroid));
    }

But now I have different error:

erreur : 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
                    ^

Comment: You are trying to copy a `QObject` (or some derived class) but its copy constructor is private. This question is not the place is ask that, and if you are having more problems you should ask a different question. Your problem with `SettingsAsteroid` has been solved. Before asking a new question, try to reduce your new question to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing so aids others in helping, and often helps you uncover the problem by yourself